# To log JSF facelet(xhtml) expression language error on page in log file using log4j?

Tags: jsf, el

I wonder if there is a way to log the EL(Expression Language) errors on jsf-facelet(xhtml) page in log file using log4j? I tried the following loggers but in vain..

```
 <logger name="javax.faces">
    <level value="WARN" />
    <appender-ref ref="appLogFile"/>
 </logger>
 <logger name="javax.servlet">
    <level value="WARN" />
    <appender-ref ref="appLogFile"/>
 </logger>
 <logger name="org.apache">
    <level value="WARN" />
    <appender-ref ref="appLogFile"/>
 </logger>
```

Actually I have some simple mathematical calculations in JSF EL like `#{intA/intB}` `#{intA-intB-intC}` etc. and want to log if error occurs when the customer is browsing our web application.

Any hints are appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to your log4j properties or XML ,

# log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,myapp

log4j.appender.myapp=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myapp.file=/var/log/appLogFile.log
log4j.appender.myapp.maxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.myapp.maxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.myapp.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myapp.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p | %d | %F:%L | %m%n

log4j.logger.javax.faces=DEBUG
log4j.logger.javax.el=ERROR
log4j.logger.com.sun.faces=DEBUG

 <logger name="javax.faces">
    <level value="WARN" />
    <appender-ref ref="appLogFile"/>
 </logger>

  <logger name="javax.el">
    <level value="ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="appLogFile"/>
 </logger>
```

or

If you want to use an error page,

```
 <error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.el.ELException</exception-type>
        <location>/elError.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
```

elError.xhtml can be somethhing like ,

```
<h:panelGrid>
    <h:outputText value="Exception Occured:" />
        <h:outputText  value="#{ErrorBean.message}" />  
</h:panelGrid>
```

Create a ManagedBean to get the error and do logging to database or log4j ,

```
@ManagedBean
        public class ErrorBean{

            public String getMessage() {

                FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
                Map requestMap = context.getExternalContext().getRequestMap();
                Throwable exception = (Throwable) 
                               requestMap.get("javax.servlet.error.exception");

                // Log the error in database or log4j

                return ex.getMessage();
            }
        }
```